# Response.Write does not working on Production

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, web-services, asmx

I have a C# WebService (ASMX) with the following code:

```
if (!SomeValidation())
{
    //context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    //context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/text";
    context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
    context.Response.Status = "400 Bad Request";
    context.Response.StatusDescription = "Bad Request";
    context.Response.Write("Error Message");
    //context.Response.Write("{ ErrorMessage: "Error Message" }");
    context.Response.End();
    return;
}
```

This ASMX is called using AJAX, and its error function has:

```
error: function (request, status, error) {
    if (request.status === 400) {
        ShowMessage("nWarning", request.responseText);
        console.log(request);
    } else {
        ShowMessage("nFailure", "Error.");
        console.error(request);
        console.error(status);
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

When I execute the code on my machine, the correct message is displayed, but when I publish the project, it does not work and shows the Status Code message.

Why is it happening?

**OBS:** The commented code are things that I have and do not worked.

Comment: what web server?

Answer (score -1):

At the top of your method, before writing to the response, call `Response.Clear`

At the bottom, before you call `Response.End`, call `Response.Flush`.

**Edit**
You'll actually want to use `Response.Close` instead of End. End is a a harsh way to close a Request, as it aborts the thread.

**Edit2**
As per the [documentation for `HttpResponse#Close`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.close(v=vs.110).aspx), you're going to want to call [`HttpApplication#CompleteRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.completerequest(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Still not working, but I do not get the Edit2. How should I call the CompleteRequest method?

Comment: I've foubd a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526396/how-to-response-write-on-iis7-5, the problem was in the web.config file.